# Definition of Euler-Lagrange equation and properties, where can I find?

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, critical-point-theory

I'm studying a paper and in the introduction appears the following:
It is well known that existence of critical points and solvability of Euler-Lagrange equations are related, and there is and extensive literature about critical points which are minimizers, specially for functionals defined on the Sobolev space $W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega),\; p>1,$ by
$$J(u)=\int_{\Omega}\mathcal{F}(x,u,Du) dx,$$
where $\Omega$ is bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N.$

**DOUBT:** However, I'm struggling to find this extensive literature, and I also would like to find definition and properties of Euler-Lagrange equations.

Thanks in advance.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: I think any calculus of variations book will have this result, try Dacorogna's Introduction to Calculus of Variations for example.

Comment: @CheeHan I've studied with this exact book. However, in that book, they assume we have the background I'm asking here.

Comment: By background, you meant Sobolev spaces?

Comment: If that's the case, then try Dacorogna's Direct Method in the Calculus of Variations.

Comment: No, I've read that too. By background, I mean how to build an Euler-Lagrange Equation from a given Functional in Sobolev Spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These [lecture notes](https://sites.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/hel-97.pdf) by Piotr Hajłasz might have the introductory level you are looking for:

> The lectures will be divided into two almost independent streams. One
> of them is the theory of Sobolev spaces with numerous aspects which go
> far beyond the calculus of variations. The second stream is just
> calculus of variations. The theory of Sobolev spaces is a basic
> technical tool for the calculus of variations, however it suffices to
> know only basic results for most of the applications in that context.

Comment: Yes, this will help. I start reading, these lecture notes might help with another good book I found, which is: Semilinear Elliptic Equations for Beginners (Marino Badiale and Enrico Serra). They explain even how $-div$ appears at the beginning of the Euler-Lagrange equations. Thank you very much for your help.